# Android: Keep internal files after updating app

Tags: android, file-io, google-play, internal

I've seen multiple instances where people claim that updating an Android app does *not* remove its internal files. However, I'm reading and creating a file using `openFileInput()` and `openFileOutput()` respectively, which works fine, until the app is updated where apparently the file can not be read, or is deleted.

As I'm developing a game, I would like to avoid `SharedPreferences`.

As saving progress is more or less mandatory, would writing to an external location be a better alternative? The user shouldn't although be able to tamper with the file (its a serialisation).

Otherwise, is there a way to keep the internal file after updating? Thanks

Comment: "I've seen multiple instances where people claim that updating an Android app does not remove its internal files" -- that is correct. "until the app is updated where apparently the file can not be read, or is deleted" -- a normal app update does not remove files. Please provide a [mcve], including the details of how you are updating the app. For example, uninstalling and reinstalling the app is not an update; uninstalling the app will remove the app's files from internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use an SQLite database for this purpose. Updating the app will leave the database untouched unless you explicitely instruct your app to change or delete it.