# Keeping saved files of app after an update

Tags: java, android

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846167/android-keep-internal-files-after-updating-app), it's not a duplicate.

I'm pretty new to Android-Development, so my way to store personal data on the device might be not the best one.

However, when I update the App, the stored files aren't found anymore.

```
File path = myContext.getFilesDir();
File pathUse = new File(path, "lists.ser");

if(!pathUse.exists()) {
    try {
        pathUse.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

try(ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pathUse))) {
    os.writeObject(myObject);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I store the data that way, that it is kept after an update?

Comment: Try Saving them to external files directory. Do you mean they get deleted when you reinstall the app when it is present? Or when you delete it, then install it again?

Comment: I don't know if the files are deleted or just not found after that. But I'm not talking about deleting and reinstalling the app, I'm talking about updating the app through the app-store.

Comment: How can I save them to external files directory in a general way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal files are removed only if you uninstall and reinstall. An upgrade will not remove internal files -- and it shouldn't. Consider that if it did that, your database would be removed for every upgrade as well.

Check the official documentation for more Info [Click here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)

Hence storing the application specific data in external storage is not recommended because anyone can access it.